# Embedded for: loop inside print Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if you could have a `for` loop inside of a print statement as I am trying to sort a list of strings, and sort each string alphabetically, with as few a lines as possible. This is my code so far:

`myArray = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo']
for i in range(len(myArray)): print((''.join(sorted(list(myArray[i]),))), end=', ')`

This prints: `aahlp, aborv, acehilr, adelt, ceho`; but I want it to be in an array so that I can continue using it: `[aahlp, aborv, acehilr, adelt, ceho]`

Comment: And you'd expect this construct to do... what?

Comment: garbage in, garbage out. If you need to print the message 5 times, the print should be *inside* the loop, not the other way around.

Comment: `print(' '.join(['Hello World' for i in range(5)]))`

Comment: The easiest way to satisfy your curiosity is to test it in the interactive shell and get SyntaxError...

Comment: How about string multiplication? As in `'Hello, world!' * 5`?

Comment: I want to print a single character and then a group of strings from a list with as few a lines as possible. Other wise I would use `end=' '`

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Ask about your X, not your Y.

Comment: I still don't get the question at all... I think you want `myArray = [''.join(sorted(word)) for word in myArray]; print(*myArray, sep=', ')`?

Comment: Not really, because I want it back in the list it was in originally.

Comment: If you want a list (*not* an array), why are you using `print` at all? `new_list = [''.join(sorted(x)) for x in myArray]`

Comment: Just to see if it works

Comment: I don't know why you would expect it to. `print` writes strings to standard output, it doesn't create data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution that works:

```
print([''.join(sorted(list(myArray[i]))) for i in range(len(myArray))])
```